# How to (re)send email from a file using mutt or mail?

Tags: bash, email, mutt

I have set up exim4 to deliver a copy of all outgoing mails to a local maildir in case something goes wrong. Now something's gone wrong and I need to resend some of the mail from the local maildir.

The emails have their full headers (inc. Return-Path, To, From, Subject etc.) and body (MIME).

Is there a way to do this:

```
$ somemailcommand <theemail
```

and have it make a new attempt to deliver it?

I've tried `mutt -H theemail` which looked promising (although it starts an interactive UI) but the emails came through blank.

I've tried `mail anemail@example.com <theemail` but that just sent the headers in the body. I'm on Debian Linux.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *[bounce](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#forwarding-mail)* function (default bound to `b` key) to resend message and keep original headers.

To do so:

- a) bounce single message

  - just press `b`
- b) bounce multiple messages

  - tag messages you want using `t` or `T<PATTERN>` (see [patterns in mutt manual](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#patterns))
- then `;b` then You'll be asked to fill e-mail address
  **Bounce tagged messages to:**

Comment: Thanks, it's the "from a file" bit I'm stuck on. I am not using mutt as an email account client, I just want to use it's sending features. Is this method available if the email is in a stand-alone file (and not in an inbox somewhere)?

Comment: Doesn't work if you would like to bounce to all people included initially in the Cc list (need to copy'n'paste manually all those addresses). Any better option? Seems `Esc` + `e` does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

sendmail -t < messagefile

This command extract To: from email file, and send mail to it.